# Windows Media player Streaming doesn't open all video files on TV?

Tags: windows-media-player, video-streaming, dlna, video-codecs, smart-tv

I stream video from my PC to my Samsung Smart TV. But not all videos seems to be supported.

I have 2 video files that are mp4:

- The first I can stream it fine & watch the video,
- The second says that the device can't open the file and to check it again later.

The strange part is that these 2 files are converted using the same converter and have no difference except in duration only!

Here are the video specs for each video. Video-1 opens and video-2 doesn't:

---

#### Video 1

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\video-1.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 656 MiB
Duration                                 : 43mn 36s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 2 105 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.42.100
Xtra                                     : WM/MediaClassSecondaryID

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 43mn 36s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 906 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 2 300 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.083
Stream size                              : 595 MiB (91%)
Language                                 : English

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 43mn 36s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 59.9 MiB (9%)
Language                                 : English
```

---

#### Video 2

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\GEORGE\Desktop\video-2.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 766 MiB
Duration                                 : 50mn 15s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 2 132 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.42.100
Xtra                                     : WM/MediaClassPrimaryID

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 50mn 15s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 934 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 2 300 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.084
Stream size                              : 695 MiB (91%)
Language                                 : English

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 50mn 15s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 69.0 MiB (9%)
Language                                 : English
```

Why can't I play Video 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a problem of corrupted MP4 video. In my case, the corruption was due to the presence of a field called `*Xtra : WM/MediaClassPrimaryID*` in the header of the MP4 file. Because of this, it was impossible to play the video.

After some searches on internet, I have found the solution. I'm a software developer so I have implemented a Windows application (for Windows 7, 8 and 10) to fix the issue.

In your case, I can see that:

- video1 contains `Xtra : WM/MediaClassSecondaryID` and it it working
- video2 contains `Xtra : WM/MediaClassPrimaryID` and it it NOT working

I think that in your case also, the video is corrupted by the presence of `Xtra : WM/MediaClassPrimaryID`.

I have made my application available on Internet as a Freeware (without any limitation) which can remove the field `Xtra : WM/MediaClassPrimaryID`. You may want to try it, I hope that it will help you to recover your videos.

Here it is: http://auroraborealissoftware.jimdo.com/english/